# Cannot create a new Project Area on RTC 3.0.1

Tags: rtc

I installed (basic setup) of RTC 3.0.1 on Windows 2008 server. The setup passed ok and everything appears to be "green". However, when I navigate to the Project Areas in order to create a new one, the following error message shows up:

> The service "com.ibm.team.process.internal.service.web.ProcessWebUIService" failed to    activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.jts.auth.IApplicationContextService", failed to be activated.ID CRJAZ1972E

detailed exception:

```
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:257)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getServiceForRemoteAccess(OsgiServicesManager.java:550)
com.ibm.team.repository.servlet.AbstractTeamServerServlet.handleRequest2(AbstractTeamServerServlet.java:1805)
com.ibm.team.repository.servlet.AbstractTeamServerServlet.handleRequest(AbstractTeamServerServlet.java:1725)
com.ibm.team.repository.servlet.AbstractTeamServerServlet.service(AbstractTeamServerServlet.java:1634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:75)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:120)
com.ibm.team.repository.server.servletbridge.JazzServlet.service(JazzServlet.java:76)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:420)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.jts.auth.ApplicationContextService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.oauth.IInternalOAuthServiceProvider", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 35 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.oauth.OAuthServiceProvider" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.common.service.IContributorService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 40 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.jts.contributor.internal.JtsContributorService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.IInternalDbContributorService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 45 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.ContributorService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.common.ILicenseAdminService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 50 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.internal.license.jts.JtsLicenseService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.license.ICompatibilityLicenseService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 55 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.license.internal.LicenseService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.util.http.ICrossServerHttpClientService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 60 more.
Caused by:
The service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.util.http.CrossServerHttpClientService" failed to activate because a service it depends on, "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.internal.IJtsConfigurationStateService", failed to be activated. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1972E
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:319)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.doActivate(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:652)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:133)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
... 65 more.
Caused by:
Failed to find the service "com.ibm.team.repository.service.compatibility.internal.IJtsConfigurationStateService" with a matching filter "(validJtsConfig=true)". Use the administrative UI to verify that the server and applications are configured correctly. (com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.TeamServiceRegistryException)ID CRJAZ1135I
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.getService(ServiceProviderActivationManagerOwner.java:142)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:248)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.OsgiServicesManager.getService(OsgiServicesManager.java:257)
com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport.internal.registry.AbstractActivationManagerOwner.buildServicesMap(AbstractActivationManagerOwner.java:316)
... 68 more.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a while trying to figure out what went wrong I managed to solve it as follows:

1. I started RTC "As Administrator" on Windows 2008.
2. Somehow the JTS setup failed to correctly register the CCM application.

   To solve it, I ran the setup of the CCM application by navigating to:
   https://%hostname%:9443/ccm/setup.

It worked for me.